# How to print each line in textarea with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show the value of the textarea in my `div` `#result`, preserving linebreaks in the textarea and adding `1` at the end of each line.

Here's what I've tried to far. It only adds `1` to the last line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World !</title>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="10" id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
<div id="result"></div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test() {
  var b = document.getElementById('mytext').value+1;
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = b.replace(/\n\r?/g, '<br>');
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: @Kinglish - how does PHP relate to this question?

Comment: Ooops, wrong one. Seems like a dupe nonetheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your previous method was not working because you were adding `1` to the value and *then* splitting by linebreaks.

Instead, split the value by linebreaks (`\n`), then loop through each item, concatenate and insert into the result's innerHTML.

```js
const result = document.getElementById("result");

function test() {
  result.innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('mytext').value
    .split("\n")
    .forEach(e => result.innerHTML += e + "1" + "<br>")
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello World !</title>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea rows="10" id="mytext"></textarea>
  <button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
  <div id="result"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your help . I have one more question please "How to clear old output value when I insert new value in textarea it's add to previous output ? "

Comment: @A7medAero I've updated my answer. It should clear the output now.

Answer (score 0):

As much as the first answer is "OK" - there's no need to add to innerHTML in a loop

in some cases (not something this simple) that can impact rendering and performance

set innerHTML once with this one line of code (split over multiple lines for readability

```js
function test() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById('mytext').value
    .split("\n")
    .map(v => v + 1)
    .join('<br>');
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" id="mytext"></textarea>
<button onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```js
const 
  myText   = document.querySelector('#my-text')
, myButton = document.querySelector('#my-button')
, pResult  = document.querySelector('#result')
  ;
myButton.onclick = () =>
  {
  pResult.innerHTML = myText.value
                      .split(/\n\r?/)
                      .reduce((t,l,i) => // better with a number?
                        t + `${i+1} - ${l}<br>`
                        ,'') 
  }
```

```css
#my-text {
  height : 6em;
  }
#result {
  margin   : .7em;
  padding  : .4em;
  height   : 6em;
  width    : 10em;
  border   : 1px solid lightblue;
  resize   : both;
  overflow : auto;
  }
```

```html
<textarea id="my-text"></textarea>
<button id="my-button">Click Me</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can match the text instead of replace new lines

**Example**

```
function test() {
 var b = document.getElementById('mytext').value;
 var matchText = b.match(/.+/gi);
 var res = document.getElementById('result');
 var txt = ""
 for(i = 0; i < matchText.length; i++) {
    txt += i+1 + ": "+ matchText[i] + "<br>"
  }
   res.innerHTML = txt
}
```